# Windows 7 crashed - how to recover private keys from certificate store?

Tags: windows-7, windows, certificate

long story short - something got screwed with my boot loader, then drivers gave me blue screen etc - after 2 days of googling I decided to stop and just reinstall the windows (keeping the image of old one on a separate partition of course).

Is there a way to recover private keys for SSL certificates which were installed in MMC->Certificates? Is it possible to use some kind of recovery CD to boot and then "login" to offline image? I think if I can do that, I should be able to connect via MMC and do export for the certificates.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it before but if you have access to NTuser.dat file from the old computer you can load the hive in to your Registry.

1. Open Regedit
2. Highlight HKEY_USERS and then select Load Hive from the Registry menu.
3. Select the NTuser.dat file from the old computer
4. When prompted for Key Name, input their Username.

The editor will insert the user's Registry data into HKEY_USERS under the user's name.

http://scilnet.fortlewis.edu/tech/Users/load_HKEY_USERS.htm

Then look under

> HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\

Now mind you they will be un-readable binary blobs so they need to be decoded. NEver tried it but its worth a shot to export the entries and then import them into your own HKEY_CURRENT_USER, restart and then use the MMC snap in to see if you can access them. Good luck?